# Delaying event listener from firing an event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am developing an app where on mouse wheel up and down navigates the user to different routes in the App. I also have animations corresponding to which way the user scrolls: when scrolling down the next route will intialize from below and the previous route will exit from below, and vice-versa.

this part has been simple enough to implement as per the code below(link to full live working example at the bottom of this post):

Custom Hook UseAppDirection.js

```react
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"

function useAppDirection(navDown, navUp, directionValueDown, directionValueUp) {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const { pathname } = location;
    const [isUp, setIsUp] = useState(false);



    useEffect(() => {
        function handleNavigation(e) {
            if (e.deltaY > 1) {
                setIsUp(false)
                setTimeout(() => {
                    navigate(navDown, { state: { value: directionValueDown } });
                }, 200)
            } else if (e.deltaY < 1) {
                setIsUp(true)
                setTimeout(() => {
                    navigate(navUp, { state: { value: directionValueUp } });
                }, 200)
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener("wheel", handleNavigation);

        return () => window.removeEventListener("wheel", handleNavigation);
    }, [pathname]);




    return { location, isUp }
}

export default useAppDirection
```

AboutMe.js

```react
import React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import useAppDirection from "../Hooks/useAppDirection";


export default function AboutMe() {
    const { isUp, location } = useAppDirection("/work", "/skills", 1000, -1000);

    return (
        <motion.div
            className="aboutme--top"
            initial={{ opacity: 0, y: location.state.value, transition: { duration: 0.8 } }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0, transition: { duration: 0.8 } }}
            exit={{ opacity: 0, y:  isUp ? 1300 : -1300, transition: { duration: 0.8 } }}
        >
        </motion.div >
    )
}
```

However one major problem I have ran into is when a user scrolls one direction and in mid transition scrolls the opposite direction; both animations occur simultaneously resulting in a very ugly and janky transition as two components are simultaneously both leaving and exiting.

My question is, how can I modify my code to ensure that only when one transition has completed can the next one start? I am happy to have the listener be disabled for the duration of the transition and only be re-enabled on a set timer (the time taken for the transition to complete  ~ 0.8seconds).

Currently the event is able to fire as soon as the transition occurs, and I am unable to find a solution for it.

live working example below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-w42djd?embed=1&file=Hooks/useAppDirection.js

Comment: Seems you could probably take advantage of [onAnimationComplete](https://www.framer.com/docs/component/###onanimationcomplete) in some way.

Comment: any ideas on how I would utilize it? it seems to useful more for running another function once the animation ends, my problem is that I have two animations beginning (and ending) at the same time so there is a conflict, I need the other animation to not start at all until the other component has finished its animation & transition.

Comment: You mentioned being happy to disable a listener during a transition, to be enabled on a timer. Instead of a timer I'm suggesting to use a callback function to re-enable a listener once a transition has completed.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what that would look like. From my understanding wouldn't the 2nd unintended event fire irregardless?

Comment: I don't believe it would be picked up if the event listener is "disabled" while any prior event/animation is still "processing". That is, if you disable the listener when a route transition/animation begins.